# What kind of API should I use to create components in Tridion 2009 using an ASP.NET project?

Tags: 2009, tom.net, api

I'm looking for information on how to create and publish dynamically components in Tridion 2009.

What kind of API do I need and are there any tutorials around to get started with it?

Comment: In case it doesn't come up, "dynamic" *retrieval* and *display* would be the Content Delivery API, which has .NET and Java versions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The TOM.NET API in 2009 was read-only, so your only option is the TOM API, and for .NET code, you can use the TOM Interop DLLs.

You will need to reference `Tridion.ContentManager.Interop.cm_tom.dll` and `Tridion.ContentManager.Interop.cm_defines.dll` (found in the `[Tridion]\bin\client\PIA` folder on your CMS)

Then you can use the TOM API in your .NET code (check out the TOM API guide for details on creating new items):

```
using Tridion.ContentManager.Interop.TDS;
using Tridion.ContentManager.Interop.TDSDefines;

TDSE tdse = new TDSE();
tdse.Impersonate(@"domain\user");
tdse.Initialize();

Page page = (Page)tdse.GetObject("tcm:1-2-64", EnumOpenMode.OpenModeEdit, Constants.URINULL, XMLReadFilter.XMLReadData);
page.Title = "new title";
page.Save(true);

ReleaseCom(page);
ReleaseCom(tdse);

private static void ReleaseCom(object instance)
{
  if (instance != null)
  {
    try
    {
      Marshal.ReleaseComObject(instance);
    }
    catch
    {
      // log potential memory leak
    }
  }
}
```

Please note the usage of `Marshal.ReleaseComObject` on every object you use, since this is Com Interop code, and you need to properly release your objects. There is more written about that in other questions, just search for `Marshal.ReleaseComObject`

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what Bart said, below is the Link (Login Required) to get the Detailed Documentation for the TOM API:

https://www.sdltridionworld.com/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=/downloads/documentation/SDLTridion2009/index.aspx

You need to login with valid SDL account and need to download the Full Documentation ZIP file.

Comment: Thanks for this link. I think there is an account i can use. Have to talk about this with my manager